# No metadata for "User" was found using TypeOrm

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to get a [basic setup](https://github.com/ripper234/typeorm-naming-strategy) working using TypeORM, and getting this error following the setup.

Here is a REPL (just do `yarn install && yarn db:dev` followed by `yarn db:migrate && yarn start` to reproduce the error)

```
Inserting a new user into the database...
{ EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "User" was found.
    at new EntityMetadataNotFoundError (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/src/error/EntityMetadataNotFoundError.ts:9:9)
    at Connection.getMetadata (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/src/connection/Connection.ts:313:19)
    at /Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts:77:55
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts:71:30)
    at step (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:13:53)
    at /Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/admin/work/typeorm-naming-strategy/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:3:12)
  name: 'EntityMetadataNotFound',
  message: 'No metadata for "User" was found.' }
```

Answer (score 62):

Adding answer bit late but its very common error.

There are two main reasons for above error. In OrmConfig,

1. You have used *.ts instead of *.js. For example,

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts']  <-- Wrong
```

It should be

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.js']
```

2. entities path is wrong. Make sure, entities path is defined according to dist folder not src folder.

Comment: It's actually the other way around. .ts is correct, .js wrong.

Comment: @user2912903 changing .ts with .js did the job for me, i was reading some article and they also used .ts, can someone explain what's happening ?

Comment: @Kekson It depends on how you use it. Both can be done, but most of the time it's a best practice to use `.js`. The `.ts` file can run because it uses `ts-node` but TypeORM and TypeScript and the whole ecosystem kind of backfire on one another. Just check the TypeORM doc, they provide both ways to run on TS or JS. I can write a whole thing about it, but you just need to note my first few sentences.

Answer (score 42):

The problem is on `ormConfig`

Please try to use this:

```js
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}']
```

Comment: This worked for me. Please can you explain what this the meaning of this path `__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'`

Comment: When the app is started, TS code is transpiled into JS and thus TypeORM config is also transpiled into JS and TypeORM cannot read it unless you set `entities` to read both JS and TS files. The `{js,ts}` syntax used here simply means to read any file with `js` or `ts` suffix.

Comment: Thank you. this work ed for me. This was transpilation issue.

Answer (score 27):

In my case I had forgotten to add new entity ( User in your case ) to app.module.ts .
Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
// app.module.ts

@Module({
    imports: [
      TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        ...
        entities: [User]
        ...
      }),
      ...
    ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also made the same mistake

Comment: Can anyone explain why do I still have to do this, even though I have set ` autoLoadEntities: true`?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it... `Session` is the only entity that is not called using `TypeOrm.forFeature([Session])` in another module declaration, which is a requirement for the `autoloadEntities` function.

Answer (score 16):

If your app is using the latest DataSource instead of OrmConfig (like apps using the latest version of typeorm (0.3.1 the moment i'm writing theses lines)), make sure to call `initialize()` method of your DataSource object inside your data-source.ts file before using it anywhere in your app.

Comment: Would you be able to show a snippet of this in use (presumably in Nest `main.ts`) @Barry?

Comment: nest already integrates typeorm with a dedicated npm package, configuration is done at module level thus using it is even straightforward using dependency injection see https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database @deadbyte

Answer (score 10):

in my case, i was changing one EmployeeSchema to EmployeeEntity, but i forgot the entity annotation on it:

```
@Entity()
export class Employee {
```

Answer (score 6):

enable autoLoadEntities in app.module.ts

```
imports: [UserModule,
  TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    autoLoadEntities: true
  })
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this is the best answer basically the error happens when you didn't add the Entity of your module to the TypeORM config for DataSource in your app.module.ts file, so you can either explicitly create and array and list the entities in your app or tell TypeORM to autoLoad all your entities.

Comment: what needs to be understood is that this answer works in combination with what others said... so you need to add both:
 TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
    autoLoadEntities: true
  })

@Malindu can you please update your answer?
Otherwise, this is best answer...

Answer (score 5):

Following will ensure that the file extensions used by TypeORM are both .js and .ts

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}']
```

change this in your config file.

Answer (score 5):

In my case i forgot to use `connection.connect()` method after creation of connection and got same error when using `manager.find()`.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have established a connection with the database before using the entities. In my case, I was using the `AppDataSource` before it was initialized. Here is how I fixed it:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { Season } from "src/models/Season";

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "test-db",
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: [Season],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [],
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    console.log("Connection initialized with database...");
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

export const getDataSource = (delay = 3000): Promise<DataSource> => {
  if (AppDataSource.isInitialized) return Promise.resolve(AppDataSource);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (AppDataSource.isInitialized) resolve(AppDataSource);
      else reject("Failed to create connection with database");
    }, delay);
  });
};
```

And in your services where you want to use the DataSource:

```
import { getDataSource } from "src/config/data-source";
import { Season } from "src/models/Season";

const init = async (event) => {
  const AppDataSource = await getDataSource();
  const seasonRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(Season);
  // Your business logic
};
```

You can also extend my function to add retry logic if required :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this err message, but i solved in a different way, it could also happen when you already have a table called "users" for example, and your model User is not with the same columns and configs as your table, in my case my table had a column called posts with a default value, and my model hadn't that default value set up, so before you check the entities directory on the **ormconfig.json** i highly recommend you check if your models are with the same properties and configs as your database table

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and later found I haven't call the functionality to connect the DB. Just by calling the connection fixed my issue.

```js
    export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      ....
    
    });
    
    
    let dataSource: DataSource;
    
    export const ConnectDb = async () => {
        dataSource = await AppDataSource.initialize();
```

And use this to connect in your function.

Another occasion I got a similar message when I run `$ npm test` without properly mocking Jest.spyOn() method and fixed it by:

```js
jest.spyOn(db, 'MySQLDbCon').mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve());
const updateResult = {}
as UpdateResult;
jest.spyOn(db.SQLDataSource, 'getRepository').mockReturnValue({
    update: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(updateResult),
  }
  as unknown as Repository < unknown > );
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue, in my case I was using NestJS version `9.0.0`.

In `app.module` while importing `typeORM` module, one of the properties `autoLoadEntities` was turned to `false`. So locally when I was trying to connect to DB, it was throwing me this error while writing a `find() query`.

Correct way to import typeORM:

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'mongodb',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) || 27017,
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        ssl: false,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
        logging: true,
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

for the new version of typeORM you must register the entity folder and the file extension

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  entities: ["dirname/**.ts"],
});
```

in the example I used ts, but you can switch to js if that's your case.

in case you use the ormconfig file

```
{
  "entities":["/**.ts"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe my issue was caused by accidentally having both ormconfig.json and ormconfig.ts

Comment: oh yeah, it can get confused over that. If it says EntityMetadataNotFound you know the problem is your entities haven't been located, otherwise, the metadata would be loaded. So the place to start is wherever you define your entities

Answer (score 1):

I'll contribute to this list of answers. In my case, I'm using a fancy-pants IDE that likes to auto-transpile the `ts` code into `js` without my knowledge. The issue I had was, the resulting `js` file was no bueno. Killing these auto-gen'd files was the answer.

The relevant bit of my  `ormconfig` looks like:

```json
{
  ...
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts", "test/entity-mocks/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"]
  ...
}
```

Actually, I even tried the methods above to also include transpiled `js` files if they exist and I got other weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the solutions above, changing the typeORM version solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone runs into the same problem i had. I had to do two different things going against me:

I was missing the declaration of entity in ormConfig:

```
ormConfig={
  ...,
  entities: [
     ...,
     UserEntity
  ]

}
```

And since i was making changes  (afterwards) to an existing entity, the cache was throwing a similar error. The solution for this was to remove the projects root folders: **dist/** folder. Thou this might only be a Nest.js + TypeOrm issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the entity in question was the only one giving the error. The rest of entities worked fine.

The automatic import failed to write correctly the name of the file.

```
import { BillingInfo } from "../entity/Billinginfo";
```

instead of

```
import { BillingInfo } from "../entity/BillingInfo";
```

The I for Info should be capital. The IDE also failed to show any errors on this import.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also come up if you have a nodemon.json file in your project.

So after including your entity directory for both build and dev in the entities array

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
type: 'mysql',
host: DB_HOST_DEV,
port: Number(DB_PORT),
username: DB_USER_DEV,
password: DB_PASSWORD_DEV,
database: DB_NAME_DEV,
synchronize: false,
logging: false,
entities: [ 
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod"
    ? "build/entity/*{.ts,.js}"
    : "src/entity/*{.ts,.js}",
],
migrations: ["src/migration/*.ts"],
subscribers: [],
```

})

and still getting this error, remove the nodemon.json file if you have it in your project

Answer (score 1):

ForMe ， i have set error path cause this problem

my error code like this

[image]

and then i check the `entities` path . i modify the path to correct. then the typeorm working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides the **@Entity()** annotation, with **typeorm** version *0.3.0* and above also don't forget to put all your entities into your **DataSource**:

```
export const dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: 'data/my_database.db',
    entities: [User],
    ...
    ...
})
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#030-2022-03-17

Comment: This fixed my issue thanks!  There is also an option `autoLoadEntities: true` instead of the entities array.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only way of having the entities folder work in NestJS + TypeOrm v 0.3.11 was the following configuration:

```
const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
  name: process.env.DB_NAME,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.{ts,js}', 'src/migrations/*.{ts,js}'],
  entities: ['dist/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}', 'src/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
  migrationsRun: true,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I used this: ***autoLoadEntities: true,*** in the config file instead of: entities: ***[__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],*** as seen in  this github link: *https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/05-sql-typeorm/src/app.module.ts*

Answer (score 1):

"No Metadata" error on TypeORM could be a LOT of causes. But in most of the cases the Entity was writen wrong or the database connection is not being succesful. I wrote [this article](https://medium.com/@JorgeSantanaDeveloper/troubleshooting-the-no-metadata-was-found-error-in-typeorm-2fab1003b099) trying to cover most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

my fail was that instead of using Models I used Requests. Requests are loaded earlier so it end it undefined. Try to move your Model Class to Models

Answer (score 0):

Add your entity in `orm.config.ts` file.

```
entities: [empData,user],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I omitted this @Entity() decorator on the entity class. So immediately I fixed this, and it worked for me.
Example:

```
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Message {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  conversationId: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  sender: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was two things, while using it with NestJS:

- There was two entities with the same name (but different tables)

Once I fixed it, the error still happened, then I got to point two:

- Delete the dist/build directory

Not sure how the build process works for typeorm, but once I deleted that and ran the project again it worked. Seems like it was not updating the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've **provided a wrong db password**. Instead of receiving an error message like "connection to db failed" I've got the error message below.

EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "User" was found.

Answer (score 0):

Using TypeORM with NestJS, for me the issue was that I was setting the `migrations` property of the `TypeOrmModuleOptions` object for the `TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions` useFactory method, when instead I should've only set it on the migrations config, which uses the standard TypeORM `DataSource` type.

This is what I ended up with:

`typeorm.config.ts`

```js
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import {
  TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions,
  TypeOrmModuleOptions,
} from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const postgresDataSourceConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  ...
  // NO migrations property here
  // Had to add this as well
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  ...
};

export const typeormAsyncConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  useFactory: async (): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => {
    return postgresDataSourceConfig;
  },
};

// Needed to work with migrations, not used by NestJS itself
export const postgresDataSource = new DataSource({
  ...postgresDataSourceConfig,
  type: 'postgres',
  // Instead use it here, because the TypeORM Nest Module does not care for migrations
  // They must be done outside of NestJS entirely
  migrations: ['src/database/migrations/*.ts'],
});
```

`migrations.config.ts`

```js
import { postgresDataSource } from './typeorm.config';

export default postgresDataSource;
```

And the script to run TypeORM CLI was

`"typeorm-cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/database/migrations.config.ts"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Should never fall

```
DB_ENTITIES=[dist/**/*.entity.js]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get "Error: No metadata for Quiz was found" because different version. Here is my solution:

- quiz.module.ts: imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Quiz])],
- quiz.service.ts: constructor(@InjectRepository(Quiz) private quizRepository: Repository){}

I dont need quiz.repository.ts file
---- from a youtube comment and the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was not properly initialised apollo server I had to export this function:

```
export async function startApolloServer() {
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
typeDefs,
resolvers,
});
await server.start();

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.use((req: any, res: any) => {
res.status(200);
res.send("Hello!");
res.end();
});

await new Promise((resolve) => app.listen({ port: 4001 }, resolve));
console.log(` Server ready at 
http://localhost:4001${server.graphqlPath}`);
return { server, app };
}
```

and call it in my index.ts file

```
AppDataSource.initialize()
.then(async () => {
startApolloServer();
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

After a such few google it, I found a specific solution for using TypeORM inside tests (in my case Mocha and Chai).

I was troubling the same error 'No metadata for "x" was found...'

Basically I noticed that sometimes this error doesn't popped up when running tests.

So my solution for it is:

```
beforeEach(done => setTimeout(done, 500));
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was working, but the issue arose for just one function. It is a REST express server.

The problem is that I performed a specific DB operation **before** the Database was initialized. That action was automatically triggered as soon as the server was up.

So if you have found no solution so far, it can just be a *timing* issue.

Answer (score -1):

i think you forgot to include `@Entity()` decorator on top of your entity class.
I had the same issue and it was fixed by adding it.