# TypeORM configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, ts-node

I'm writing a Typescript NodeJs server.

I use TypeORM and for work it needs a config file with two arrays of paths or functions to entities and migrations.

Right now it looks like

```
{
  subscribers: ['build/subscriber/*.js'],
  migrations: ['build/migration/*.js'],
}
```

When I'm starting my app it'll be transpile with tsc and create a build folder with js files. And in these case everything works fine.

But TypeORM have a CLI tool, and I want use it for creating migrations. But I don't want to transpile all projects just to create migration. I'd run the CLI command with ts-node and use ts files. But without transpiration "build/subscriber/*.js" doesn't exist.

Can I do something to use TypeORM CLI without transpiration the whole project?

P.s. If I change config paths to

```
{
    subscribers: ['src/subscriber/*.ts'],
    migrations: ['src/migration/*.ts'],
}
```

The project will stop running.
May there exists a way to see in code transpiled them or not to implement something like optional paths

```
{
    subscribers: isTranspiled ?['build/subscriber/*.js'] : ['src/subscriber/*.ts'],
    migrations: isTranspiled ? ['build/migration/*.js'] : ['src/migration/*.ts'],
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `__dirname` instead, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743549/5923666) will help you

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem and do the following:

```
// Hack for webpack
const migrations_path = __dirname.trim() === '/usr/src/app/dist' ? __dirname.trim() : path.join(__dirname, '..');

{
  ...
  migrations: [migrations_path + '/typeorm/migrations/*.{js,ts}'],
}
```

You'll need to update for your own paths, but this is how we support the dist for production webpack build and for our src folder during hot reloading.