# Expo TypeORM EntityMetadataNotFoundError

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm

I'm trying to use typeorm on an expo project through driver expo-sqlite but I've been stuck on to this metadata `EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.` error. As far as I've understood this line `entities: [User]` on `config.ts` it's connected to the error, searching for it I found some [people discussing bad configuration on entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562162/no-metadata-for-user-was-found-using-typeorm), but they are pointing directly to the filesystem path, and I'm passing through the DataSource the User class. I wrote this code based on [This repo](https://github.com/jgabriel1/expo-sqlite-typeorm-article) and [TypeORM strange? example](https://github.com/typeorm/expo-example)

I've tried this already:

`entities: ['./entities/*.entity.ts']`

Error stack

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.]
at http://192.168.2.2:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:166214:321 in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules/typeorm/browser/error/TypeORMError.js:5:25 in constructor
at http://192.168.2.2:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:167099:321 in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules/typeorm/browser/error/EntityMetadataNotFoundError.js:5:24 in constructor
at node_modules/typeorm/browser/data-source/DataSource.js:281:8 in getMetadata
at node_modules/typeorm/browser/repository/Repository.js:19:19 in get__metadata
at node_modules/typeorm/browser/repository/Repository.js:72:9 in save
at App.tsx:31:18 in wrapper
at App.tsx:25:8 in wrapper
at App.tsx:33:15 in useEffect$argument_0
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:58:4 in renderApplication
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:202:4 in runApplication
```

<User.entity.ts>

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm"

@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Column()
    lastName: string

    @Column()
    age: number
}
```

<config.ts>

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm/browser"

import { User } from "./entities/User.entity"


export const AppDataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'expo',
    database: 'zipzop.db',
    driver: SQLite,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [User],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
}


export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(AppDataSourceOptions)
```

<app.ts>

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import useCachedResources from './src/hooks/useCachedResources';
import useColorScheme from './src/hooks/useColorScheme';
import Navigation from './src/navigation';


import { AppDataSource } from './src/database/config';
import { User } from './src/database/entities/User.entity'


export default function App(props : any) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!AppDataSource.isInitialized){
            AppDataSource.initialize()
            .then(() => console.log("Database initialization SUCESS"))
            .catch((err) => console.log("Database initialization FAILED", err))
            .finally(async () => {
            })
        } else {
            console.log("Database initialization ALREADY")
        }
        async function wrapper() {
            let repository = AppDataSource.getRepository(User)
            let user = new User()
            user.firstName = "Francisco"
            user.lastName = "Pena"
            user.age = 24
            await repository.save(user)
        }
        wrapper()

        async function wrapper2() {
            let repository = AppDataSource.getRepository(User)
            const allUsers = await repository.find()
            console.log(allUsers)
        }
    })


    const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    if (!isLoadingComplete) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
            <StatusBar />
            </SafeAreaProvider>
            );
    }
}
```

[Repository](https://gitlab.com/fpc7063/entitymetadataerror) with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, have a look at https://github.com/typeorm/expo-example/pull/5

The expo-example for typeorm has just been updated

Comment: can you share what you saw in the PR that fixed your issue. I have looked through the PR and I must be missing something in my code because mine is still not working. However, I can't put my fingers on what is different.

Comment: Have a look to the patch here : https://github.com/typeorm/expo-example/blob/master/patches/typeorm%2B0.3.6.patch

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because some import is using resource from your TypeORM DataSource before it has been completely initialized.

Remember that all imported modules are evaluated before the body of the module, as well stated in this SO answer: [What is the defined execution order of ES6 imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551366/what-is-the-defined-execution-order-of-es6-imports#35552247)

Your code repo is missing some parts, like the "types" folder, so I could not properly check all your imports. But it is important to keep that in mind.

Now, back to your code above, from what I could see your `useEffect` hook in the `app.ts` script initializes the `AppDataSource` but that is a Promise that will be executed asynchronously. Immediately after, without waiting for the promise to complete execution, you call the `wrapper()` function that is making use of the not initiated repository with `let repository = AppDataSource.getRepository(User)`. This code is probably the cause of the error.

In this case you should add a control state variable that you will set inside the "then" part of you `AppDataSource.initialize()`. That control variable will trigger the other code, like the code inside your `wrapper()` function, after the initialization process has been properly completed.