# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "TransactionRepository" was found

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to create a backend using NestJS and I am getting this error

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "TransactionRepository" was found.
> EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "TransactionRepository" was found.

Everything is set up correctly. The entity is also set up correctly. What did I do wrong? Kindly help

transaction.repository.ts

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { Transaction } from "../entities/transaction.entity";

@EntityRepository(Transaction)
export class TransactionRepository extends Repository<Transaction> {
}
```

transaction.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CreateTransactionDto } from '../dto/create-transaction.dto';
import { TransactionRepository } from '../repositories/transaction.repository';

@Injectable()
export class TransactionService {
    
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TransactionRepository) private transactionRepository: TransactionRepository,
    ){}
    
    getAllTransactions() {
        return [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }

    async createTransaction(transaction: CreateTransactionDto) {
        return await this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the related module code, wherever you've registered the service and repository.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [No metadata for "User" was found using TypeOrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562162/no-metadata-for-user-was-found-using-typeorm)

it looks like you have to modify this line in omrconfig.json and had `ts`:

```
  "entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
```

Comment: This solution didn't work

Comment: Can you show your `omrconfig.json` file