# Error executing query EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Profile" was found

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, typeorm, supertest

I need to run some tests with supertest and im using Typeorm in this project. But I'm getting the following error. I checked the db connection and everything mentioned in the following [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562162/no-metadata-for-user-was-found-using-typeorm) but none of them worked. Is it something wrong with the configuration?

profile entity: https://github.com/sef-global/scholarx-backend/blob/main/src/entity/profile.entity.ts

Here's the code: https://github.com/sef-global/scholarx-backend

```
console.error
      Error executing query EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Profile" was found.
          at DataSource.getMetadata (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:444:30)
          at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/repository/Repository.ts:53:40)
          at Repository.createQueryBuilder (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/repository/Repository.ts:82:18)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/services/auth.service.ts:68:8
          at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/services/auth.service.ts:8:71
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/services/auth.service.ts:4:12)
          at login (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/src/services/auth.service.ts:56:60)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at next (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
          at Route.dispatch (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
          at Function.process_params (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
          at next (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
          at Function.handle (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
          at router (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at trim_prefix (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
          at Function.process_params (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
          at next (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
          at initialize (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:98:5)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at trim_prefix (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
          at Function.process_params (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
          at next (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
          at cors (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
          at originCallback (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
          at optionsCallback (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
          at corsMiddleware (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at trim_prefix (/Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
          at /Users/anjula/scholarx-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
          at Function.process_params (/Users/anjula/scholarx-
```

I tried everything mentioned here: [No metadata for "User" was found using TypeOrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562162/no-metadata-for-user-was-found-using-typeorm)